# extract value from xml element with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I would like to use xpath to extract values from a url string within a xml element, such as:

```
<Artist_Export>
<Geonames>http://www.geonames.org/3175121/l-aquila.html</Geonames>
</Artist_Export>
```

In this case I would like to extract "3175121" from http://www.geonames.org/3175121/l-aquila.html

Do you have some clues on how to do so with xpath?

edit: I tried to use:

```
substring(/Artist_Export/Geonames, string-length(/Artist_Export/Geonames) -20)
```

but I got only the last part of it. Should be used substring(stringoffsetlength)    which "Returns a section of the string. The section starts at offset (which is a number), and is as long as the value provided at length (also a number)." but I don't know how to use it really

Comment: Show how you tried to solve your issue

Comment: You need to specify which version of XPath. XPath 2.0 supports regular expressions which makes this easy. You also need to tell us what the general rules are: for example does the URI always start with `http://www.geonames.org/` and is the number always the same length?

Comment: yes, the structure is always the same for all the URI: http://www.geonames.org/3175121/, so "http://www.geonames.org/" + 7 numerical digit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out a solution. You should use

substring(/Path/subpath, starting_char_numer,number_of_chars)

such as, in the case

```
<Artist_Export>
<Geonames>http://www.geonames.org/3175121/l-aquila.html</Geonames>
</Artist_Export
```

if you want to extract "3175121", the right command is

```
substring(/Artist_Export/Geonames, 25,7)
```

Hope it is going to be useful to someone else :)